# What's the most efficient way to get an attribute from a HMT join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

Right now I have an `Artist` model setup as a self-join in the context where an artist can belong to a `group` and a group as many `members` (i.e. artists). I also have a join table that establishes these memberships. In the join table there's an enum attribute `status` that determines whether an artist is an active member.

While experimenting in the rails console I managed to retrieve an artist's membership status doing the following:

```
Artist.first.memberships.find_by(group: 3).status
=> "active"
```

I'd like to bring this into my project as a an instance method for artists but felt this lookup chain could be improved.

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships, class_name: "Membership", foreign_key: :group_id
  has_many :members, through: :group_memberships

  has_many :memberships, foreign_key: :artist_id
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:active, :inactive]

  belongs_to :member, class_name: "Artist", foreign_key: :artist_id
  belongs_to :group, class_name: "Artist"
end
```

I was thinking in my view enumerating through each group member and showing their status:

```
<% @artist.members.each do |member| %>
  <%= member.group_status(@artist) %>
<% end %>
```

And this would be how the instance method would be written:

```
def group_status(group)
  memberships.find_by(group: group).status
end
```

And there a better approach in doing this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't have a separate model for `Group`? It's melting my brain trying to visualise how the artist has a many-to-many relationship with something called a "group" that is actually occupying the same table as the artists!

Comment: While putting this together I found that artists and groups shared almost the exact same attributes. With this in mind I concluded that it would be cumbersome to have two separate controllers or enumerate two instance variables for every view I wish to use. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: what are the attributes for each?

Comment: Not just the attributes (name, origin, etc) but also the additional associations (albums, genres, labels).

Answer (score 0):

You need [ActiveRecord Association Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/models/artist.rb
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships do
      def status_by_group group
         select(:status).find_by(group_id: group)
      end
  end
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end
```

This way, you'll be able to do:

```
@artist = Artist.find params[:id]
@artist.memberships.status_by_group(2) #-> should return object with status of Membership
```

---

There is a better way.

If you wanted to append the `status` attribute to your `group` objects:

```
@artist.groups.find(1).status
```

...you'd be able to use the ActiveRecord Association Extension functionality, but this time with the `proxy_association` objects.

I've done it before and created the following code:

```
#app/models/artist.rb
has_many :memberships
has_many :groups, through: :memberships, extend: GroupStatus

#app/models/concerns/group_status.rb
module GroupStatus

      #Load
      def load
        statuses.each do |status|
            proxy_association.target << status
        end
      end

      private

      #Status
      def statuses
        return_array = []
        through_collection.each_with_index do |through,i|
            associate = through.send(reflection_name)
            associate.assign_attributes({status: items[i]})
            return_array.concat Array.new(1).fill( associate )
        end
        return_array
     end

     #######################
     #      Variables      #
     #######################

     #Association
     def reflection_name
        proxy_association.source_reflection.name
     end

     #Foreign Key
     def through_source_key
        proxy_association.reflection.source_reflection.foreign_key
     end

     #Primary Key
     def through_primary_key
        proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.active_record_primary_key
     end

     #Through Name
     def through_name
        proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.name
     end

     #Through
     def through_collection
        proxy_association.owner.send through_name
     end

     #Statuses
     def items
        through_collection.map(&:status)
     end

     #Target
     def target_collection
        proxy_association.target
     end

end
```